# use of php $row variable

Tags: php, row, predefined-variables

Is $row a predefined variable in php (or does it have some other built-in functionality)? I have several times seen it used without prior reference in the code, but haven't found any documentation or explanation about it yet.

Comment: $row is not a predefined variable,but it is the most meaningful and hence most used variable name to store a database row.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such a predefined variable, you've just seen a variable declaration/initialization.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a convention, you can use any name you want, however is good to use something simple, clear that make sense...